# UITableView titleForHeaderInSection prints headers to console twice then crashes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

In the method below `titleForHeaderInSection`, for some reason the NSLog prints out the headers twice and then the app crashes in `objc_msgSend`. I can't understand why this would cause the app to crash?

It would seem from research that crashes in objc_msgSend are caused by sending messages to already freed objects, but is that the case here?

My sectionNames array is populated in viewDidLoad.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {   

    NSString *title = nil;
    title=[sectionNames objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(title);
    return title;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you populating your sectionNames array? It's possible that the array, not the string, is getting released prematurely.

**UPDATE:**

Your problem is that `+arrayWithArray:` creates an autoreleased array, which gets released when the current run loop finishes. You need to either retain sectionNames or use `-initWithArray:`

Comment: `sectionNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[aPOI.attributes allKeys]];` where aPOI is an instance variable and attributes is a dictionary